# VueJS hash files with CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, cryptojs

I'm reaching out to you because I'm terribly stuck with a Vue project...

I'm experiencing a little issue when trying to move a jQuery project over to Vue. CryptoJS is working a charm and I can create hashes from strings.

However, I'm still struggling reading the actual file, as the nested functions are throwing errors. Specifically getting errors on the `callbackRead` function.

```
App.vue?234e:280 Uncaught TypeError: this.callbackRead is not a function
at FileReader.reader.onload (App.vue?234e:280)
```

Can you please give me some guidance on how to successfully translate the script to VUE JS? ( https://medium.com/@0xVaccaro/hashing-big-file-with-filereader-js-e0a5c898fc98 )

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Here is what I got so far: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuejs-file-crypter-kjirp

Best regards,
Mac

Comment: Please provide an [mre].  Don't link to code on another site, please add your code to your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from this section:

```js
reader.onload = function(evt) {
    this.callbackRead(this, file, evt, callbackProgress, callbackFinal);
};
```

The problem is that `this` refers to the wrong object. Your `onload` handler is a different function from the surrounding code and whenever you enter a new function the value of `this` changes.

There are several possible solutions.

Aliasing `this`:

```js
const that = this;

reader.onload = function(evt) {
    that.callbackRead(that, file, evt, callbackProgress, callbackFinal);
};
```

Binding `this`:

```js
reader.onload = function(evt) {
    this.callbackRead(this, file, evt, callbackProgress, callbackFinal);
}.bind(this);
```

Using an arrow function, which won't alter the value of `this`:

```js
reader.onload = evt => {
    this.callbackRead(this, file, evt, callbackProgress, callbackFinal);
};
```